# SnapsToDevicePixels, UseLayoutRounding and BitmapScalingMode seems not to work

Tags: wpf, xaml, snapstodevicepixels

when im programming with Visual Studio C# 2010 on WPF, some Text is very unclear, regardless of setting SnapsToDevicePixels to true, UseLayoutRounding to true and BitmapScalingMode to HighQuality. You can see the Problem in the image...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXPAF.png

Anyone got an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode`. [MSDN reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx).

Comment: Great! TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" did it! Thanks alot :)